# Backup Folder and Ambiguity of Definition of Variables

Tags: c#, backup, ambiguity

Ok, so I am converting code to C#, and I am using Visual Studios 2013. I have a backup folder with a copy of various files from the project in it because I cannot build the project unless they are in there. If the files are not in there, an error saying, "source file 'FolderPath\Backup\FileName' could not be found. So to solve that issue I put a copy of the file into that folder. However, when I do that I get the error 'Ambiguity between 'variable' and 'variable', because it seems to being reading the variable off the backup copy and the original copy. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get the compiler to not read the backup copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem right. (Why this backup folder is needed at all.) I think 'backup folder' means a folder in the solution explorer. So it may be that you have to switch the 'Build action' of the files in the backup folder to 'None'. (Right click on the files->Properties then see Property Window) (I hope those are the right terms in English; I have a German version of VS)

Comment: That's fine. Is it right enough for accepting it ;-)